# I can't understand the order of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, machine-learning

I'm reading a book called Bishop - Pattern Recognition and Machine learning.
[image]

M is the order of the polynomial.
I can't understand it. How can I find M? What's number M?

Comment: Looks as if the order is the highest degree (in $x$) appearing, among the monomials of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the polynomial ($M$) is the highest exponent of $x$ that appears in the expression of the polynomial. For example, $x^2$ is a degree-2 polynomial and $1+3x+3x^2+x^3$ is a degree-3 polynomial